# SABRE REST API FULL SCHEMA DOCUMENTATION

Tags: sabre

I am doing some tests with SABRE API, particularly the Advanced Calendar Search and this search returns quite a lot of objects. 
When I try to understand the schema of these returned objects on the model definition at the lower part of the page it just shows: "Please see full specification in json schema and json schema description files - API resources". So, where can I check this full specification for the returned json object?

Answer (score 0):

We can see the details in Example value or we can download yaml file(link is placed in top of the page) and convert to json file.